# How to add new product packs to cart?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to add pack product to cart programatically, my action in `ModuleFrontController` is viewed like this:

```
public function initPack(){
    $product = new Pack();

    $product->tax_name = 'tva1';
    $product->tax_rate = '10%';
    $product->id_manufacturer = 1;
    $product->id_supplier = 1;
    $product->id_category_default = 1;
    $product->id_shop_default = 1;
    $product->manufacturer_name = 'rrr';
    $product->supplier_name = 'rrr';
    $product->name =  array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') =>  'coffret-4');;
    $product->description = 'description 1';
    $product->description_short = 'description short';
    $product->quantity = 20;
    $product->on_sale = false;
    $product->online_only = true;
    $product->reference = '1234567889';
    $product->ean13     = 12233;
    $product->upc = 12233;
    $product->link_rewrite = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') =>  'coffret-4');
    $product->meta_description = 'fff';
    $product->meta_keywords = 'ff';
    $product->meta_title  = 'fff';
    $product->visibility= 'both';

    $product->date_add = date("j, n, Y");
    $product->location = '';
    $product->category = 16;
    $product->text_fields = 1;
    $product->condition = 'new';
    $product->on_sale = true;

    if($product->save())
        $product->add();
    else{
        echo 'erooooooor';
        die();
    }

    Pack::addItem($product->id, 1, 1);
    Pack::addItem($product->id, 3, 1);

    $attribute = $product->addProductAttribute(12, 234, 2344, 12, 20, 1, 222,
    $id_supplier = null, 222, 1);

    $cart->add($product, array('qty' => 1));
    $cart->save();
}
```

the number of product in cart is incremented, but no name, price, ... is shown

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop treat the pack like a product, so you have to assign a price to this pack, e.g.

```
$product->price = 10.00;
```

Otherwise I'll suggest to you edit your code like this:

```
public function initPack(){
    $id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id;
    // New product with right language id
    $product = new Pack($id_lang);

    // I'm not sure that is the right way to assign the tax
    // $product->tax_name = 'tva1';
    // $product->tax_rate = '10%';
    $product->id_tax_rules_group = // Here you have to write the right id of tax_rules_group, you can find in Localization -> Tax Rules

    $product->id_manufacturer = 1; // Not mandatory, check if this id exists really
    $product->id_supplier = 1; // Not mandatory, check if this id exists really
    // $product->id_category_default = 1; // Corrected after
    $product->id_shop_default = 1;
    $product->manufacturer_name = 'rrr';
    $product->supplier_name = 'rrr';
    $product->name =  'coffret-4';
    $product->description = 'description 1';
    $product->description_short = 'description short';
    $product->quantity = 20;
    $product->on_sale = false; // True or false? :)
    $product->online_only = true;
    $product->reference = '1234567889'; // Not mandatory
    $product->ean13     = 12233; // Not mandatory
    $product->upc = 12233; // Not mandatory
    // Link rewrite generated by Tools class
    $product->link_rewrite = Tools::link_rewrite($product->name);
    $product->meta_description = 'fff';
    $product->meta_keywords = 'ff';
    $product->meta_title  = 'fff';
    $product->visibility= 'both';

    // $product->date_add = date("j, n, Y"); // Useless, it's 'automatic' :)
    // $product->location = ''; // Useless
    // You have to set the category field like an array
    $product->category[0] = 16;
    // And give also the default category id
    $product->id_category_default = 16;
    $product->text_fields = 1;
    $product->condition = 'new';
    $product->on_sale = true; // True or false? :)
    // We have to tell to prestashop that product is a 'pack'
    $product->cache_is_pack = 1;

    if($product->save())
        $product->add();
    else{
        echo 'erooooooor';
        die();
    }

    // After save the product we must update categories associations
    if ( isset( $product->id_category ) && is_array($product->id_category) ) {
        $product->updateCategories(array_map('intval', $product->id_category));
    }

    Pack::addItem($product->id, 1, 1);
    Pack::addItem($product->id, 3, 1);

    // I don't think so you can add the product attribute to a pack
    // $attribute = $product->addProductAttribute(12, 234, 2344, 12, 20, 1, 222, null, 222, 1);

    $cart->add($product, array('qty' => 1));
    $cart->save();
}
```

I'm assuming that you don't have multishop enabled. I didn't tested this code, but I guess it works ;), try and let me know ;)